# How do I read the result received from a multi-query FQL into strings in objective c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

I want to be able to extract data from the result of my multi-query.

I am using this code to make a multi-query:

```
NSString *query =
@"{"
@"'friends':'SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() LIMIT 25',"
@"'friendinfo':'SELECT uid, name, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM #friends)',"
@"}";

NSDictionary *queryParam = @{ @"q": query };

[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/fql"
                             parameters:queryParam
                             HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error) {
                          if (error) {
                              NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                          } else {
                              NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);
                          }
                      }];
```

And then I print out the result to the command line, and I see all of the data which I want to see.

```
Result: {
data =     (
            {
        "fql_result_set" =             (
                            {
                uid2 = 12345;
            },
                            {
                uid2 = 12345;
            }
        );
        name = friends;
    },
            {
        "fql_result_set" =             (
                            {
                name = "gg";
                "pic_big" = "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/gg";
                sex = gg;
                uid = 12345;
            },

                            {
                name = "gg";
                "pic_big" = "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/gg";
                sex = gg;
                uid = 12345;
            },
                            {
                name = "gg";
                "pic_big" = "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/gg";
                sex = gg;
                uid = 12345;
            }
        );
        name = friendinfo;
    }
);
}
```

I just can't figure out how to extract the name, picture url, gender, and uid from each entry from the result.  I feel like I need to use some combination of arrays and dictionaries, but I'm not sure how.  Thanks in advance for any help. :)

Answer (score 0):

bit late but, this is how ive done it for any one else trying.....

```
//get data into array
NSArray *data = [result objectForKey:@"data"];

//loop queries in array
for (NSArray *nextQuery in data) {

    //debug query name (use this for if statement to handle query data)       
    NSLog(@"query name - %@", [nextQuery valueForKeyPath:@"name"]);

    //get query data
    NSArray *queryData = [nextQuery valueForKeyPath:@"fql_result_set"];

    //
    NSLog(@"uid %@", [queryData valueForKeyPath:@"uid"])

}
```

you can get to nested objects by using value for key path and the dot operator.

Hope this helps.